# JPA EntityManager returns stale values without entityManager.clear

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA EntityManager with Spring/Hibernate and entitymanager seems to be behaving weird when I update an entity from a hibernate session and then view it from a different hibernate session.

I have the following configuration in my application:

1. EHCache, and **enabled Second Level Cache**
2. `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)` on the entities
3. Extended `PersistenceContext` on `em`
4. `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`

Calling `em.clear()` solves this issue. I tried disabling second level caching, query caching etc but did not help. I expected the entitymanager to take care of this. Is this expected ? I am looking for a cleaner approach, and do away with calling `em.clear()`.

Answer (score 2):

These stale entities are managed by extended persistence context, independently from transactions. In JPA 2.0 specification this is spelled as follows:

> Note that when a new transaction is begun, the managed objects in an
>   extended persistence context are not reloaded from the database.

There is not any built in functionality to automatically refresh them. What you can do is using clear or EntityManager.refresh for single entities, and maybe cascade REFRESH operation in you mappings.

Comment: Could it be something related to URLs ? I noticed that when I update the entities, the url is save.html and when I am fetching its time/list.json - which gives stale. However, when I tried fetching with time/list.html, it works fine ! even though both urls are mapped to use same service... I am puzzled now. Does this extended persistent context do url based caching ?

Comment: Hibernate knows nothing about the URL of your web application as it's designed to work in JavaSE and JavaEE environments with no dependency on `javax.servlet` APIs (or any API related with the web tier). Your issue must be related to the fact of using two different sessions.

Comment: Of course, I should have known that. As I said, I am puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of the problem. It was because my updates and fetch were being done from two different servlet contexts. I have now put them into same context and it works fine.